# Firebase: Hostname match not found (auth/captcha-check-failed). However vercel domain name is present in firebase console

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, subdomain, vercel

When implementing signInWithPhoneNumber using firebase in react 18 application, I kept facing the same error as mentioned `Hostname match not found (auth/captcha-check-failed)` and I have added my domain in the authorized domains in firebase console.

I have done this with before with signInWithPopup and it has worked flawlessly,
Now I have observed that the domain I am facing issue with is with vercel custom domain
`https://**-******-****-**-**-9cf5b3-*********.vercel.app/`
so I have added the domain name `vercel.app` in the authorized section

Is there something I am missing?

I have added my domain in the authorized domains in firebase console.
I expected when I added the domain, it should have worked as shown in documentation
Worked with signInWithPopup but not working with signInWithPhoneNumber
Works when adding full domain

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.